# How can i combine json data in a array but aggregate the data on minutes?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm writing a azure function where i recieve data from Azure StreamAnalytics and send it to a relational database. After a couple of months of testing this function the database growth was insane. 
I write 300.000 rows of data every single day and this is just from 1 datasource. Now i want to aggregate the data i recieve per minute and get the average value of that minute. 
After researching how to aggregate json data i couldnt find a article that could help me.

I made a custom Machine class where i have a couple of functions so i can store the data. I can already store the milisecond data i now want to store the minute data.

```
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Host = "test",
                Username = "test",
                Password = "test",
                Database = "test",
            };

            using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    string content = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

                    foreach (var data in result)
                    {
                        Machine machine = new Machine
                        {
                            Id = data.data.sID,
                            Path = data.data.sXPath,
                            Type = data.data.sType,
                            MeasurementTimestamp = data.data.dtTimeStamp,
                        };

                        foreach (JProperty items in data.data.items)
                        {
                            string[] split = Regex.Split(items.Name, @"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])");
                            string dataType = machine.GetDataType(split[0]);
                            string measurementValue = (string)items.Value;

                            if (!machine.MeasurementTypeExists(items.Name, dataType, connection))
                            {
                                machine.AddMeasurementType(items.Name, dataType, connection);
                            }

                            int typeId = machine.GetTypeID(machine.Type, connection);

                            if(machine.MachineExists(machine.Id, connection) && machine.MeasurementTypeExists(items.Name, dataType, connection) && machine.PointOfMeasurementExists(machine.Id, typeId, machine.Path, connection))
                            {
                                int measurementTypeId = machine.GetMeasurementTypeID(items.Name, dataType, connection);
                                int pointOfMeasurementId = machine.GetPointOfMeasurementID(machine.Path, machine.Id, typeId, connection);

                                // Miliseconds
                                machine.AddMeasurementMs(measurementValue, machine.MeasurementTimestamp, machine.Id, measurementTypeId, pointOfMeasurementId, connection);


                                // Minutes
                                machine.AddMeasurementMin(measurementValue, machine.MeasurementTimestamp, machine.Id, measurementTypeId, pointOfMeasurementId, connection);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Executed");
        }
    }
```

How can i aggregate the json data to store the average value of a minute using my AddMeasurementMin function?
Any push in the right direction will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the date and minutes in two separate fields in your database, and then you can use queries to aggregate entries per minute and calculate nros of entries.

From your code, you need to use the timestamp to get the minutes, so can quickly do something like this

```
var entryDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(machine.MeasurementTimestamp);

// Minutes
machine.AddMeasurementMin(measurementValue, entryDate.Minute, machine.Id, measurementTypeId, pointOfMeasurementId, connection);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, great push into the right direction